# Set the first fire time of the trigger to the date mentioned in StartAt()

Tags: c#, cron, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I have defined the following trigger for a job:

```
var postbagJobTrigger = (ICronTrigger)TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("cronJOBBER", "Campaigns")
        .WithCronSchedule("0 13 9 1/5 * ? *")
        .StartAt(new DateTime(2014, 12, 3))
        .EndAt(new DateTime(2015, 3, 3))
        .WithPriority(1)
        .Build();
```

What I expect is that the first time of my trigger should be `DateTime(2014, 12, 3)`. But when I see the firing schedule of this job, the first time is `DateTime(2014, 12, 6)`. And when I add the `StartNow()` condition, the first time will be the time that meets the schedule starting now which is `DateTime(2014, 10, 31)`. How can I tell the trigger to have its first run at my `StartAt()` time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems ok to me.
The problem is in your **CRON** expression. This is the result for December:

```
8   Monday, December 1, 2014 9:13 AM
9   Saturday, December 6, 2014 9:13 AM
10  Thursday, December 11, 2014 9:13 AM
11  Tuesday, December 16, 2014 9:13 AM
12  Sunday, December 21, 2014 9:13 AM
13  Friday, December 26, 2014 9:13 AM
14  Wednesday, December 31, 2014 9:13 AM
```

You instructed Quartz.Net to start counting from December the 3rd.

You can check your expression with [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/).

It's better not to use `DateTime`. This is the definition for `StartAt`:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Set the time the Trigger should start at - the trigger may or may not fire
//     at this time - depending upon the schedule configured for the Trigger. However
//     the Trigger will NOT fire before this time, regardless of the Trigger's schedule.
//
// Parameters:
//   startTimeUtc:
//     the start time for the Trigger.
//
// Returns:
//     the updated TriggerBuilder
public TriggerBuilder StartAt(DateTimeOffset startTimeUtc);
```

You should use a `DateTimeOffset`. This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546101(v=vs.110).aspx) might help you.

**UPDATE:**

Quartz.Net uses your local [TimeZone](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/e4e71b78bea5a4b7cb41408902207e9880b027ad/src/Quartz/Impl/Triggers/CronTriggerImpl.cs#L196) unless you specify a different one.

If you want to check what TimeZone your trigger is using:

```
((CronTriggerImpl)trigger).TimeZone
```

A better approach is to use [DateBuilder](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/e4e71b78bea5a4b7cb41408902207e9880b027ad/src/Quartz/DateBuilder.cs):

```
DateTimeOffset dtNow = DateBuilder.DateOf(10, 32, 30, 28, 10, 2014);
```

which [uses](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/e4e71b78bea5a4b7cb41408902207e9880b027ad/src/Quartz/DateBuilder.cs#L342) your local timezone.

If you want to achieve what you're asking you can do something like this:

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
    .Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "myGroup")
    .StartAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(0, 0, 0, 3, 12, 2014))
    .EndAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2015))
    //.WithCronSchedule("0 0 0 1/5 * ? *")
    .WithCalendarIntervalSchedule(f=>f.WithIntervalInDays(5))
    .WithPriority(1)
    .Build();
```

or

```
ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
    .Create()
    .WithIdentity("trigger1", "myGroup")
    .StartAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(0, 0, 0, 3, 12, 2014))
    .EndAt(DateBuilder.DateOf(0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 2015))
    // .WithCronSchedule("0 0 12 1/5 * ? *")
    .WithSimpleSchedule(f=>f.WithIntervalInHours(24 * 5).RepeatForever())
    .WithPriority(1)
    .Build();
```

If you want to check your schedules call `GetNextXFireTimes`. This is the function :

```
private void GetNextXFireTimes(ITrigger trigger, int counts)
{
    var dt = trigger.GetNextFireTimeUtc();
    for (int i = 0; i < (counts-1); i++)
    {
        if (dt == null)
        {
            break;
        }
    Console.WriteLine(dt.Value.ToLocalTime());
    dt = trigger.GetFireTimeAfter(dt);
    }
}
```

This is the way **Cron Expressions** work:

```
* * * * *
- - - - -
| | | | |
| | | | +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
| | | +------- month (1 - 12)
| | +--------- day of month (1 - 31)
| +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

Comment: I will check on the program. Thank you! I have one more question regarding the Utc. What is the deal there? Will my jobs be triggered according to their `Utc`? time. Do I have to do something extra so that jobs will be run at my local time? (I live in Sweden by the way which is +1:00).

Comment: @Pedram: I've updated my answer with some more reference. Cheers.

Comment: Yes I am already getting help from CronMaker. I think the function is working properly. If I am not mistaken, it creates the triggers for every 5 days and when I say `StartAt()` it starts from the first trigger that is immediately after that date. But what I was wondering was whether there was a way so the first trigger will fire on the `StartAt()` time and then the rest of the triggers go according to our cron.

Comment: Now that I am thinking, if I mention my start day and time in my cron expression and not in `StartAt()` I already get what I want, right?

Comment: I don't think your cron expression will ever work. See update.

Comment: @LeftyX the problem is I have to use cron expressions because they come from user entry in my program. So I don't think I can use `WithSimpleSchedule`.

Comment: @LeftyX and yes I am already using  `GetNextFireTimeUtc()` and it helps me alot. I use a `while` with `HasValue`.

Comment: @Lefty If I change my cron schedule and remove the time from it (run at midnight) and then I apply `StartAt()` with the hour and minute, do you think that will do the job?

Comment: @LeftyX No apparently it does not work the way I explained in the above comment.

Comment: @LeftyX your solution is correct and I chose it as the answer because I did not mention in the question that I have to use cron expression. But I have to find a solution for my need. Because as I told you, the schedule comes from user input and they choose their triggers to happen daily, weekly, monthly, on specific days, weeks, etc. The above solution is correct for the time we would like to run a schedule that triggers every 5 X days starting from a specific time. If we could generalize it so we could add this `StartAt()` to all the schedules, it would be great.

Comment: @LeftyX `CronScheduleBuilder()`? Had no idea it existed. Gonna give it a try.

Comment: @Pedram: the problem is with [cron expressions](https://code.google.com/p/ncrontab/). You will never achieve what you're looking for. Sorry to disappoint

Comment: @LeftyX Then I will keep wondering how `Windows Task Scheduler` works when you can tell it to run a job every Monday and Tuesday, start tomorrow 5 o'clock and that will be the start of your scheduler.

Comment: @Pedram: Does it use cron expressions? Expressions like days-of-the-week are managed very well with cron.